# MongoDB Federation Concurrency Limit and Queuing

Tags: mongodb

I'm planning to utilize MongoDB Atlas Data Federation's $out feature to export data to Amazon S3 on a daily basis. I'm employing the MongoDB scheduler to execute a script daily to initiate this process. Since the trigger's execution time is restricted to 2 minutes, all aggregation pipeline operations are executed in the background. According to the documentation, there's a maximum of 30 concurrent federated queries possible. What happens if more queries are submitted? Will they be rejected or queued?

Has anyone employed MongoDB Federation for S3 exports and encountered positive outcomes? I'd appreciate hearing your experiences.